# Why does the network usage shown in Task Manager not equal that in Resource Monitor?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, task-manager, resource-monitor

Why, in Windows 7, is the network usage shown under Task Manager always higher than reported by Resource Monitor for total network I/O, which also seems lower than the sum of individual network activities (per process) reported in Resource Monitor.

[image: E.g., in this screenshot (https://i.imgur.com/68e5pZc.png)*]

the total network activity is reported variously as

- 0.05% of 65 Mbps in Task Manager, ≅ 4 KBps
- 4 Kbps as Network I/O in Resource Monitor, ≅ 0.5 KBps, and finally
- 1361 Bps as the sum of the Total columns of both the Processes with Network Activity and the Network Activity tables, ≅ 1.4 KBps

Is this due to the different monitors counting different types of traffic? Or could it be due to unauthorized communication/a virus?

Comment: don't do math on your own. activate also send/receive values in taskmgr and compare them now